# How to get interface name in implemented function

Tags: javascript

Below is the code I have used to achieve interface concept in javascript:

```
function Interface1(ImplementingClass) {
  return {
       implementedFunction : ImplementingClass.implementedFunction
  }
}

function  Interface2(ImplementingClass) {

   return {
      implementedFunction : ImplementingClass.implementedFunction
   }
}

function ImplementingClass() {
 this.implementedFunction = function() {
     // How to get implemented interface name, for 
     // example here interface name should be Interface1???
 }
}


function Test() {
    this.test = function() {
         return new Interface1(new ImplementingClass());
    }
}


var test = new Test();  
test.test().implementedFunction();
```

Question: How to get interface name in implemented function, for example in java we use instance of operator

```
if(this instance of Interface) { 
    // Do something  
}
```

Comment: Do you just mean `instanceof`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: I have tried instanceof operator but it does not work if we implement more than one interface.

Comment: JavaScript is not a classical language, so concepts like interfaces and classes do not directly translate. Still, many of these concepts can still be emulated.

Comment: Just to be clear: You cannot instanciate an interface, you instanciate and object that implements this interface. To refer to this instance inside the object itself you can you the keywork "this"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) won't work - it's only for prototypical inheritance from a constructor function's `prototype` object. If you need information about your interface, you will need to place it on your interface object:

```
function Interface(implementingInstance) {
    return {
        interfaceName: "MyInterface",
        implementedFunction : implementingInstance.implementingFunction
    }
}

function ImplementingClass() {
    this.implementingFunction = function() {
        console.log(this.interfaceName);
    }
}
/* maybe helpful:
ImplementingClass.prototype.interfaceName = "noInterface"; // real instance
*/

function Test() {
    this.test = function() {
        return Interface(new ImplementingClass());
    }
}

new Test().test().implementedFunction();
// calls `implementingFunction` on the object with the `interfaceName` property
```